# Как присвоить дату к объекту (пример на изображении в вопросе)?

Tags: ios, swift, дата, datetime

Как присвоить дату и время ячейке, чтобы при добавлении нового события время указывало, например, "было добавлено вчера" или "22.11.2017 года". У меня при обновлении ресурса новое время присваивается к старым событиям. Что нужно указывать, чтобы сохранение происходило? Я не могу понять, что ещё нужно добавлять, интервал или другая функция какая-то существует. Уже в playgrounde прорабатывал много статей. Очень буду благодарен за помощь!!!!! Почему-то старая дата всё время меняется на новую. Прикрепляю скриншот образец[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let sportCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sportCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0  {

        let insertRow = (soccerString.count - 1) - indexPath.row
        let soccer = soccerString[insertRow]

        sportCell.matchLabel.text = soccer.matchS

        soccerString[insertRow].imagePrS.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
            sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil
        }
    }
    else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

        let newIndex = (basketString.count - 1) - indexPath.row
        let basket = basketString[newIndex]
        sportCell.matchLabel.text = basket.matchB
        basketString[newIndex].imagePrB.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
            sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil        
        }            
    }  
    else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {

        let newInt = (tennisString.count - 1) - indexPath.row
        sportCell.matchLabel.text = tennisString[newInt].matchT

        tennisString[newInt].imagePrT.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
            sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil
        }    
    }

    sportCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

    let date = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: date)
    let dateYes = dateFormatter.string(from: yesterday!)
    print(dateYes)
    let today = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: date)
    let dateToDay = dateFormatter.string(from: today!)
    print(dateToDay)
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_UA")
    dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true

    sportCell.dataSave.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    sportCell.setNeedsLayout()
    sportCell.layoutIfNeeded()

    return sportCell
}
```

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, более детально что вы хотите и какя у вас логика. Если говорить про ячейку таблицы, то данные для ячейки берутся из DataSource.

Comment: Я хочу при добавлении нового события , чтоб выводило время .Тип такой:Сегодня , вчера и дата (24.11.2017) если событие давно было загружено.У меня при попытки давлении новой ячейки , старая дата уходит и не сохраняется, и показывает новую дату, добавленного события.

Comment: @ShurikTennisist Не посмотрев на Ваш код очень сложно будет дать дельный совет.

Comment: Вот пожалуйста обновил добавляю мой код

Comment: @ShurikTennisist это явно не весь необходимый код. Как Вы добавляете данные в таблицу? По нажатию на кнопку? Приведите пожалуйста фрагмент кода с добавлением новых элементов в таблицу. Или у Вас массивы soccerString, basketString и tennisString никогда не меняются?

Answer (score 0):

Если я все-таки правильно вас понял то вот что я вижу. Вы просто перезаписываете данные в ячейки. Вам нужно иметь **источник данных** и уже после этого выводить эти данные из источника в соответствующие ячейки. В этом коде вы для каждой ячейки формируете дату как при ее создании так и при переиспользовании. Сохраняйте дату вместе с событиями (можете сохранять просто дату получения, а форматирование делать в ячейки).

Comment: А можно на примере показать.Я не много не понял!!! Мне на одном форуме объяснили , но не до конца уловил метод.